# custom variable via custom category > design

Tags: product, category

Is there any way to set custom variable name with value in `catalog > category > custom deign`

Basically what i want a user is on category A he will get option to buy product from cat b and get offer

so basically i want to show url of category b when user browses category A.

any easy way to do this .

Comment: mour,Magento did not provide this type of feature you to customization in this case

Comment: yeah i know that's way asking , can i create custom variable in "catalog > category > custom deign"

Comment: put 301 redirection on  categoryA.html  to  categoryB.html

Comment: no redirection just link at top to go to product of category B

Comment: yes possible,create an new field at using installler , can i put code here?

Comment: yeah please do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to put new Category attribute under `Custom Design` tab then you need use tag

'group'.That means when you create attribute then you need to set group `Custom Design`

**See Example:**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();


$installer->addAttribute("catalog_category", "is_custom_field",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "label"    => "Amit Custom ",
    "input"    => "text",
    "class"    => "",
    "source"   => "",
    "global"   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "user_defined"  => false,
    "default" => "",
    "searchable" => false,
    "filterable" => false,
    "comparable" => false,

    "visible_on_front"  => false,
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""
    'group' => "Custom Design"

    ));
$installer->endSetup();
```

Study Guide: [here](https://www.ashsmith.io/2013/03/quick-tip-adding-custom-category-attributes-to-magento/)

Comment: thanks, but a help what to do to show dropdown with value as child of parent category (or sibling of current category)

Comment: will check shortly